# Trying to follow a book but my form isn't being generated, why is this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to follow a book but my form isn't being generated, why is this?
Here is my new.html.erb

```
<h1>New ad</h1>

<% form_for :ad,:url=>{:action=>'create'} do |f| %>
    <p><b>Name</b><br /><%= f.text_field :name %></p>

    <p><b>Description</b><br /><%= f.text_area :description %></p>

    <p><b>Price</b><br /><%= f.text_field :price %></p>

    <p><b>Seller</b><br /><%= f.text_field :seller_id %></p>

    <p><b>Email</b><br /><%= f.text_field :email %></p>

    <p><b>Img url</b><br /><%= f.text_field :img_url %></p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Create" %></p>
<% end %>
```

This is my ads_controller

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
    def show
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    end

    def stats
    @seller = Seller.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
    @ads = Ad.find(:all)
    end

    def new
    @ad = Ad.new
    end
end
```

and my routes is

```
resources :ads
```

This is all that I get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWlIF.jpg

Comment: Is the page empty? Does the route load? What does the source of the page look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<% form_for` should be `<%= form_for` or the form template will not be rendered.

Comment: In the book I'm reading it says Scriplets are <% %> and expressions are <%= %> That did work though, but why is this?

Comment: `form_for` is a method that takes several parameters including a block for building the content.  It returns the HTML code for the form.  If you don't use `<%=` it won't render this code.

Comment: `<%= %>` means "put the result of this expression into the html".

Comment: @PinnyM I'll mark you for answer when the time is up, thanks, trying to switch from PHP to Rails and god damn this is a confusing learning curve, partly because I'm reading from an out-dated book, but I really like the Head First o'Reily books, unless you know of a more up-to-date book or something?

Comment: Try http://guides.rubyonrails.org/, http://railscasts.com/, http://ruby.railstutorial.org/... books on evolving frameworks become out-of-date fairly quickly, unfortunately.